# Not sure of my user/location association with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to, model-associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a User and a Location models (and a Product Model too, but one problem at a time), and as I was playing with the console, I was surprised by some of the results.

**Models**

```rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Before saving filters
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

# Validations
  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

# Associations
  has_many :owned_products, class_name: "Product",
                            foreign_key: "owner_id",
                            dependent: :destroy
  has_many :borrowed_products, class_name: "Product",
                               foreign_key: "borrower_id"
  belongs_to :location

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end


Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :owner, presence: true

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :borrower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "borrower_id"
  belongs_to :location
end

Class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :products
end
```

**Migrations**

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :remember_token
      t.integer :location_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
    add_index :users, :remember_token
    add_index :users, :location_id
  end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :location_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :products, :location_id
  end
end

class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :address

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Location attributes are accessibles**

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    .
    .
    .
  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :location, :location_attributes)
    end
end
```

Then I go to my console and type :

```rb
User.create(name: "Wahou", email: "wahou@bim.com", password: "motdepasse", password_confirmation: "motdepasse")
```

What gives me :

```rb
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('wahou@bim.com') LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "remember_token", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 24 May 2013 12:27:38 UTC +00:00], ["email", "wahou@bim.com"], ["name", "Wahou"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$OhJ7SLA.vxO4N8IkZAXXQOibYQoX6G6E9/mGgmDpm8Hj48p8riDE."], ["remember_token", "-O72ULpG2tjrZSSi0BFB5A"], ["updated_at", Fri, 24 May 2013 12:27:38 UTC +00:00]]
(148.6ms)  commit transaction
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Wahou", email: "wahou@bim.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$OhJ7SLA.vxO4N8IkZAXXQOibYQoX6G6E9/mGgmDpm8Hj...", remember_token: "-O72ULpG2tjrZSSi0BFB5A", admin: false, location_id: nil, created_at: "2013-05-24 12:27:38", updated_at: "2013-05-24 12:27:38">
```

Then I type :

```rb
Location.create(address: "1, rue des prises de tête - Paris")
```

Which gives me :

```rb
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
SQL (6.0ms)  INSERT INTO "locations" ("address", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["address", "1, rue des prises de tête - Paris"], ["created_at", Fri, 24 May 2013 12:27:22 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 24 May 2013 12:27:22 UTC +00:00]]
(121.6ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Location id: 1, address: "1, rue des prises de tête - Paris", street: nil, city: nil, postal_code: nil, country: nil, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, created_at: "2013-05-24 12:27:22", updated_at: "2013-05-24 12:27:22">
```

So, fully confident, I do that :

```rb
User.first.location = Location.first
```

Which gives me :

```rb
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Location id: 1, address: "1, rue des prises de tête - Paris", street: nil, city: nil, postal_code: nil, country: nil, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, created_at: "2013-05-24 12:27:22", updated_at: "2013-05-24 12:27:22">
```

And when I type `User.first.location`, it gives me `nil` !

So I imagine I forgot something somewhere. Do you have an idea ?

(If you replace User by Product, it do exactly the same...)

---

**EDIT**

I tried to type only `User.first.location_id = 1`, and `User.first.location` is always `nil`.

The only way I find to define a user's location is to create him with location, just like that : `Location.first.users.create(name: "Wahou", email: "wahou@bim.com", password: "motdepasse", password_confirmation: "motdepasse")`. And then, it works... But what can I do when I want to update my user's location ?

---

**EDIT 2**

When I type

```rb
u = User.first
```

I see the first User is grabbed :

```rb
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Numero1 Person", email: "numero1@person.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$sNwoTjOL4eqW.clxbM5FcuiE0AmPgzr8Kz0ewXgddAvP...", remember_token: "OQ2ZnLhPutwePTqn49r5PQ", admin: false, location_id: 2, created_at: "2013-05-29 07:59:13", updated_at: "2013-05-29 09:22:00">
```

Then I affect Location.first to my first user's location :

```rb
u.location = Location.first
```

I see the first location is grabbed :

```rb
Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Location id: 1, address: "1, rue longue - 99999 LOIN - France", street: "1, rue longue", city: "LOIN", postal_code: 99999, country: "France", longitude: nil, latitude: nil, created_at: "2013-05-29 07:59:38", updated_at: "2013-05-29 07:59:38">
```

But when I want to save it...

```rb
u.save
```

...It doesn't work !

```rb
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('numero1@person.com') AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
```

---

**EDIT 3**

If I try to type the following code...

```rb
User.first.update_attributes(location: Location.first)
```

It sends me back that :

```rb
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('numero1@person.com') AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
 (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
```

**SOLVED**

Shame on me ! I forget to add the password and password_confirmation in my update_attributes. If I do that, it works !

Here is the right code :

```rb
User.first.update_attributes(password: "password", password_confirmation: "password", location: Location.first)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Aurel gave you the right hint. For explanation:

executing

```
User.first.location_id = 1
```

loads the first user into a temporary object, then sets the location_id, and then **throws it away without saving**. That's why your change is not persistent.

@Aurel's

```
u= User.first
u.location = Location.first 
u.save
```

loads the first user into `u`, sets the location of `u` and then **saves it** to make it persistent. After that

```
User.first.location
```

gives the object `Location.first`

Another way is to user `update_attribut`, that sets an attribute and saves the changes, so

```
User.first.update_attribute :location, Location.first
```

also works and makes the change persistent.

Comment: Thank you Martin, the last line works. But I don't understand why, because, when I do `User.first.update_attributes(location: Location.first)`, it doesn't work. But if I do that in a all new rails app, with only models (no controllers or view), `User.first.update_attributes(location: Location.first)` works. That's kind of strange.

And for the record, @Aurel's way didn't worked at all...

Comment: `update_attribute` needs two arguments: the attribute name and the value. `func(location: Location.first` calls `func` with **one** hash argument: `{location: Location.fist}`. That doesn't work with `update_attribute`

Comment: I think I found something [here](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/). The update_attribute method works because it doesn't care about validations and mass assignment. If update_attributes doesn't work, it means there is something wrong with my validations or mass_assignement protection, isn't it ?

Comment: I did'n see any validation in your model... But mass assignment protection only affects `User.new(attributes_hash)` or `u.update_attributes(attributes_hash)`, single assignments (`u.location=l` or `u.update_attribute`) are not covered by mass-assignment protection.

Comment: In fact I have some validations, but I didn't wrote it down here because I feared it would be too much code... I will add it now.

Comment: OK, I found my problem, it was only validations. Thank you for giving me a hint with the `update_attribute` method.

Comment: another hint: if you do it step by step, like in @Aurel's answer, and use `u.save!` it raises an exception that explains the error. `u.save` just returns `nil` in case of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you forgot to save the changes.

```
u = User.first # => <User id: 1, name: "Wahou"....
l = Location.first #=> <Location id: 1, address: "1 rue.....

# set the location
u.location = l

#Save changes
u.save

#profit
User.first.location
```